# Pi-Hole Lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, pi-hole

Does anyone know how I can use the pi-holes created lighttpd server with another application?
I don't want to install Apache next to lighttpd... Or change the default ports..
It seems like the configuration from the pi-holes web admin in lighttpd is using lighttpd exclusively?

```
# Pi-hole: A black hole for Internet advertisements
# (c) 2015, 2016 by Jacob Salmela
# Network-wide ad blocking via your Raspberry Pi
# http://pi-hole.net
# lighttpd config for Pi-hole
#
# Pi-hole is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.

server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_accesslog",
    "mod_expire",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_setenv",
    "mod_rewrite"
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.error-handler-404    = "pihole/index.html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80
accesslog.filename          = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
accesslog.format            = "%{%s}t|%V|%r|%s|%b"


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

# If the URL starts with /admin, it is the Web interface
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/admin/" {
    # Create a response header for debugging using curl -I
    setenv.add-response-header = (
        "X-Pi-hole" => "The Pi-hole Web interface is working!",
        "X-Frame-Options" => "DENY"
    )
}

# If the URL does not start with /admin, then it is a query for an ad domain
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^(?!/admin)/.*" {
    # Create a response header for debugging using curl -I
    setenv.add-response-header = ( "X-Pi-hole" => "A black hole for Internet advertisements." )
    # rewrite only js requests
    url.rewrite = ("(.*).js" => "pihole/index.js")
}
```